# Sequelize Equivalent of Mongoose Aggregate

Tags: mongoose, sequelize.js

Migrating from MongoDb to Postgres.  We were using Mongoose but now will be using Sequelize.  Having difficulty figuring out how to refactor the following function so that it returns the same output.  Here is the current Mongoose function that I need to revise to work with my Postgres db and models -

```
async listTestModels(): Promise<TestModel[]> {
const pipeline: PipelineStage[] = [{
    $group: {
        _id: "$name",
        doc: {$first: "$$ROOT"}
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        name: "$doc.name",
        version: "$doc.version",
    }
}];

return TestModel.aggregate<TestModel>(pipeline);
```

}

Comment: Can you describe using some example data how it should work and what result you expect?

Comment: @Anatoly there can be multiple templates with the same name but different version, so what I am trying to do is to return a list of templates where only the latest version for the associated template name is return.  So if I have three templates, such as [{ name: "test", version: 1 }, {name: "test", version: 2 }, {name: "test2", version: 1}] I would expect the output to be [{name: "test", version: 2 }, name: "test2", version: 1" }]

Comment: I should clarify that version attribute is a string and will actually be stored as "v1.0", "v2.0" etc.

Comment: How did you convert `v1.0` to `1` and so on in MongoDB?

Comment: I didn't, my example was incorrect, we do not store version as 1, we store it was "v1.0", "v2.0" etc, so it is stored as a string, but we need the latest one

Comment: In this case it's better to construct plain SQL query and ececute in in Sequelize as is.

Comment: It is hard to tell without model definition but you can look around `Sequelize.fn('MAX', 'version')` with `group`.